# Using analogue Takumar 28mm & 50mm AND digital Nikon 4500 WA lenses for the Olympus E-M10 Mk II camera in MACRO Photography

Tags: lens, digital, macro-converter

I wish to continue my **macro** **photography** I pursued in the **analogue** world with an Asahi **Pentax 28mm** (& 50mm)  AND in the **digital** with a Nikon **Coolpix 4500 wide-angle** lens with my recently-purchased Olympus E-M10 Mk II camera.
I currently use its 'standard' 14-42mm lens, and I feel certain that one could put the oldie lenses to good use on the Olympus. Any helpful suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Using old manual lens is standard technique in macro photography. You will need a lens adapter and a extension tube. You will probably appreciate a sturdy tripod, lens focusing rail and a wire release.

You will get good results with the 50mm, but you might struggle with the 28mm. It will give you high magnification, but little working distance; lighting your subject will be a chore.

This is a setup I sometimes use for macro photography of fishing flies - an old East German Tessar lens, on bellows and mounted on a focusing rail.

[image: Macro setup with Tessar 2.8/50]

This is one of my flies, captured with the Tessar (and image stacked).

[image: A fishing fly]

Here is unstacked photo of different flies, shot with a later model of the Tessar (optically the same the one on top photo, but with different diaphragm - I wanted to make use of the pentagonal artifacts).

[image: a bunch of fishing flies]

Comment: Belated many thanks for the helpful reply. I now have a better idea of how to tackle this feature.